Rancher set role/user permissions to redeploy deployments
I'm trying to set permissions for a role witch should be able to redeploy the applications.
I've set  access to the verbs [get, list, watch, update] for the deployments at the role's global template and the project/namespace template as well
but the user keeps getting a forbidden error when tries to redeploy the deployments
  deployments.apps "######-deployment" is forbidden: User "####" cannot update resource "deployments" in API group "apps" in the namespace "#######": Authorization failed

After getting this error, I couldn't find where to include permissions directly on the namespace configuration as the error suggests

I had to create a Project and attach the namespace to it, after this set the permissions on the project/namespace tab then it works.

As the error suggests, it indicates an authorization issue, but it doesn't involve directly modifying the namespace configurations. It may be that the verbs assigned for deployments in your role's template allows viewing and retrieving deployment information but not sufficient for redeployment and that it might be just missing update permission on the specific deployment resource in the target namespace. Granting the update verb for the deployments resource in the target namespace's RoleBinding.

Thanks man but, it is set to allow update. I had to create a Project and attach the namespace to it, after this set the permissions on the project/namespace tab then it works.
